# Copy the excel file to the folder created at specfic location in java

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have excel as input to the Rest assured and need to copy the same excel file at specified location which is generated based on the current datetime e.g. folder like 202001201447/specific folder name
I have written the code for the folder creations. Below is the code

```
public static void writeRequestAndResponse() {  


        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

        String currentDateTime = format.format(date);

        String folderPath = "E:\\OutQA\\Output\\" + currentDateTime;

        File theDir = new File(folderPath);

        // if the directory does not exist, create it
        if (!theDir.exists()) {
            System.out.println("creating directory: " + theDir.getName());
            boolean result = false;

            try {

                theDir.mkdirs();
                result = true;
            } catch (SecurityException se) {
                // handle it
                System.out.println(se.getMessage());
            }
            if (result) {
                System.out.println("Folder created");
            }
        } else if (theDir.exists()) {

            System.out.println("Folder exist");
        }


       }
```

I have problem in copy the excel file. I have to copy the excel file to the folder created at the specific locations. Below is the code of copy

```
public static void testcopy(String srcpath,String destpath)
    {

       FileInputStream instream = null;
        FileOutputStream outstream = null;

            try{
                File infile =new File(srcpath);
                File outfile =new File(destpath);

                instream = new FileInputStream(infile);
                outstream = new FileOutputStream(outfile);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                int length;
                /*copying the contents from input stream to
                 * output stream using read and write methods
                 */
                while ((length = instream.read(buffer)) > 0){
                    outstream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                //Closing the input/output file streams
                instream.close();
                outstream.close();

                System.out.println("File copied successfully!!");

            }catch(IOException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();
             }


    }
```

Comment: Can you please describe your problem more precisely? You need to provide more information.

Comment: From this code, we can understand that you are trying to create the folder, but you have described the problem as of copying the excel file. You may need to post the sample code for that too and point out the exact exception or issue with that. Then people may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the new `java.nio.file`-packages.

There you will find `java.nio.file.Files.copy` that takes as first argument a `java.nio.file.Path` to the source file and as second argument a `Path` pointing to the target location.

A `Path` can be created in the following way (I'll show it with your target location, you'll have to adapt to your source location yourself):

```
Path targetLocation = Path.of("E:", "OutQA", "Output", currentDateTime);
File theDir = targetLocation.toFile();
Path targetFile = targetLocation.resolve(targetFilename);
```

Then, call the copy method as follows:

```
Files.copy(sourceFile, targetFile);
```

As a third parameter you can specify options, e.g. what to do when the target file already exists (`java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption`). This parameter is optional.